# Can multiple attacks per action be used for casting cantrips after multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e

I am currently playing lvl 6 character: 5 Fighter/1 Sorcerer. Can I use my double attack per action to cast cantrips, like *ray of frost*, twice in one action?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Glad to see you found your answer. Also, feel free to take our [tour] if you haven't already to learn more about our site. It's good to meet you and I hope to see you around. Happy gaming!